# DiscordPy: How to get live updates on an api

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have been searching for days and havent found an answer on how to get live updates by calling an api. I want my discord bot to live update scores and stats of a player using an api. https://dathost.net/api#/default/post_matches.

Comment: You will have to create a task and loop to keep updating the data

Comment: The tradicional way to do it is using polling - fetch from the API every `n` minutes/seconds/miliseconds and look for changes. If you prefer a much better and elegant way I suggest you use the websocket protocol (if the API supports it)

Comment: @12944qwerty Does adding the task loop affect the rate limiting?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on the current usage of your bot. I recommend setting the task loop to a couple minutes

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Ive never used websockets before, but i did see an example very similar to mine using a webserver from aiohttp. I read the code but wasnt sure on how they done it.

Comment: Also, rate limiting only happens if you're interacting with the API. If you don't interact with the API, you won't be rate limited.

Comment: You should first research if your API supports the websocket protocol @bboychris168, if it does -- research about how it works and how to use it, keep a connection between the bot and the API. If the API doesn't support it -- go with what **12944qwerty** suggests.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, one method is to start your bot, and then tell it to sleep for a period of time (however long you want the interval between checking your API). When it wakes up, it will call your API. You'd then want to check to see if there were any changes between the last time you polled the API, and print out if there are changes. After this, it will go back to sleep.

Here is a simple example, using a GET snippet of the code they have provided at DatHost for python using requests. I've used SQLAlchemy in this example for database connections, but you are of course free to do raw SQL queries, or use a different ORM. If you are using SQLAlchemy, you'll need to setup the tables and columns in a structured way similar to your data.

```py
import requests
import datetime
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = Bot(command_prefix="!")

# Get request snippet from DatHost Python example 
async def call_api():
    response = requests.get(
        "https://dathost.net/api/0.1/game-servers/%s" % server["id"],
        auth=("john@doe.com", "secretPassword"),
    ).json()

    return response

# Example using SQLAlchemy to connect to a local database to store responses
# Since I don't know what data is present in this API response- I'm going to give a simple
#   example- comparing the current whole response to the last saved response- if it's different,
#    it will return true 
def is_response_changed(session, api_response):
    response_changed = False

    # Get the last saved API response
    last_request = session.query(API).order_by(API.id.dec()).first()

    # If we don't have any last request, then our DB is empty- and our data HAS changed!
    if last_request is None:
        response_changed = True

    # Else- we need to check if it's different from our current data
    else:
        # Compare our last data with our current, first will return a result or None
        compare_requests = session.query(API).filter(last_request.data == api_response).first()

        # We did not match our last data, so it HAS changed!
        if compare_requests is None:
            response_changed = True

    return response_changed


# We need to save the new API data to check against next request
def save_new_response(session, api_response):
    # This format will vary depending on how you setup your object in SQLAlchemy
    # This is a simple example assuming you're only storing the raw data and the time it was added
    new_response = API(
        data=api_response,
        date_updated=datetime.datetime.now()
        )

    session.add(new_response)
    session.commit()


# Main bot client loop
client.run(BOT_TOKEN)


# DiscordPY method to initialize bot parameters  
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # SQLAlchemy initialization 
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind="apidatabase.db")
    session = DBSession()

    # Anything in this while loop will be executed continually during your main bot loop    
    while not client.is_closed():
        api_response = await call_api()

        if is_response_changed(session, api_response):
            save_new_response(session, api_response)

            # Print out the update to a channel- you'll have to define what channel you want to update
            #   based on its snowflake ID
            await update_channel.send(f"API has updated- here's the new data! {api_response}")

        # Sleeps for 5 minutes- when it wakes up again, it will run the above while loop
        await asyncio.sleep(300)
```